# Change assigned vpn IP on OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

So on some vpn services, I saw that someone was able to automatically change the ip the user is using. The ip inside the config stayed the same however it looked like he was somehow communicating to openvpn to have a different vpn ip. Could anyone link me some documentation on how to do this or explain how because I can't find it anywhere. Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 0):

On your openvpn server, you might have a line (for example) configuring the range of available ip addresses for your clients:

```
ifconfig-pool <start-ip> <end-ip> <netmask>
```

in that case, you could specify the option `ifconfig-pool-persist` to create a config file which saves the used ip addresses - in order to always assign the same address to the same client.

The source to read this up is the man page of [openvpn](https://linux.die.net/man/8/openvpn).

The second option is to use a `client-config-dir` and inside a client-specific configuration file, use the directive
`ifconfig-push <ip> <netmask>`

also to be read inside the man page of openvpn.

A little search also could have turned up this result:
[How to set a static IP (client side) in OpenVPN?](https://serverfault.com/questions/826560/how-to-set-a-static-ip-client-side-in-openvpn)

Comment: I need it to not be within the same range.