# How to set a static IP for client on OpenVPN server with duplicate-cn?

Tags: openvpn, static-ip

To set static IP for clients with distinct certs, we can set static IP for clients following [jdmorei's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/826747/695670). However, If `duplicate-cn` is set on the server side, so that many clients share the same cert, how can I set static IP for a specific client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [IP Management With duplicate-cn](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=21275), we can use `--client-connect cmd` to write different configurations to a dynamically generated temporary file for different clients. In [Reference manual for OpenVPN 2.4](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/), it says

```
OpenVPN's internal client IP address selection algorithm works as follows:

1 Use --client-connect script generated file for static IP (first choice).
2 Use --client-config-dir file for static IP (next choice).
3 Use --ifconfig-pool allocation for dynamic IP (last choice).
```

So we can overwrite the server's `ifconfig-pool` with this script. In my case, I distinguish different clients by their IP and set static IP for a special client. When the special IP `x.x.x.x` appears, a static IP `172.0.0.3` will be distributed to this client. The script for `client-connect` is

```
$ cat /etc/openvpn/client-connect.sh 
#!/bin/bash

if [ $trusted_ip = "x.x.x.x" ]; then
    echo "static ip triggered for" $trusted_ip  
    echo "ifconfig-push 172.0.0.3 255.255.255.0" >> ${@:-1}
else
    echo "still random ip for" $trusted_ip
fi

exit 0
```

I also set the `ifconfig-pool` on the server side to avoid conflict with `172.0.0.3`

```
mode server
server 172.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 'nopool'
ifconfig-pool 172.0.0.16 172.0.0.128 255.255.255.0
```